# Java HttpURLConnection giving error 400

Tags: java, python, google-app-engine

I have a simple google app engine site running and its working fine and the webpage is being displayed in the browser.

If I use python to send a `GET` request it works perfectly but for some reason when I use java for the same it gives a `404 Response`. My java code is :

```
public static void main(String args[]){
    try {
        URL u = new URL("http://localhost:8080/gendata/");
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) u.openConnection();
        con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "text/plain");
        con.setRequestMethod("GET");
        if(con.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK){
            System.out.println("Hola");
        }else{
            System.out.println(""+con.getResponseCode());
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

My app engine get method :

```
class Writer(webapp2.RequestHandler):
def get(self):
    self.response.write('''
                <html>
                <head><title>Hello</title>
                </head>
                <body>
                <h1><center><b>This is test<br> FOO FOO
                </b></center> </h1>
                </body></html>
                ''')
```

Since I just started learning Java I wanted to know is the process different from python? And I also wanted to know if there is any Java library similar to the requests library in python ?

Comment: The Apache HttpComponents library (http://hc.apache.org/) is the standard for Java. The learning curve can be a bit steep once you get past the basics. What's the output of `curl -v http://localhost:8080/gendata/` on the same machine you're running the Java on?

Comment: Its giving me 404 error and "Hostname was not found in DNS Cache"

Comment: The hostname message is just for info. The 404 suggests the URL is invalid, so how does it work when you call it from python or the browser? Are you sure the URL you're using is the same in all cases?

Comment: Ok I got it the problem was both Oracle database and app engine were running on the same port. So browser and python was going to the app engine data whereas curl and java were going to the database page. I just changed the port from 8080 to 9080 and its working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I got it the problem was both Oracle database and app engine were running on the same port. So browser and python was going to the app engine data whereas curl and java were going to the database page. I just changed the port from 8080 to 9080 and its working fine.